# How to use Java 8 Optional properly that can conditionally return a value or throw exception?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to implement something like below code to validate inputs in my `@RestController` so that I can avoid explicit null checks, However I am stuck.

```
public @ResponseBody Response getCityDetails(@RequestParam("city") final String city) {
    Optional.of(city).ifPresent(name -> {
        // return value
        return service.getDetails(name);
    }).orElseThrow(//some Exception);
}
```

Comment: Should be `Optional.ofNullable(city)...`.

Comment: This method will not be called if there is no city parameter anyway. Change the city parameter to Optional<String>. And use map(), not ifPresent(). The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: Also, I don't think that this use of `Optional` is a) what `Optional` is intended for and b) is better in any way than a simple `if( city != null) { return ... } else { throw ...}`.

Comment: This would be a bad use of `Optional`, I mean, it's your code, do what you want. The idea is that `Optional` is better used as return value of a method that can either return `null` or a value. Instead of forcing the caller to check against `null`, you return your either present or absent value wrapped in an `Optional`. If you need to check for `null` for the argument, you'd better use Spring goodies for this, along with `hibernate-validator` (the de facto standard implementation of `bean-validation-api`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
Optional.ofNullable(city)
        .map(name ->service.getDetails(name))
        .orElseThrow(//some Exception);
```

Comment: It should be `ofNullable`, otherwise `name` will be `null` inside `map`.

Comment: You can use a method reference: `service::getDetails`

Comment: @talex the function parameter inside `Optional.map` will never be `null`. When you use `Optional.of` with a `null` argument, you will get an exception right at this point, not even reaching the `map` step.

Comment: @Holger true. I was wrong it have `Objects.requireNonNull` in constructor.